# How to add lightning Application on Salesforce1 Tabs?

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app

In a project i am working on, want to add lightning application in salesforce1 tabs(Custom tabs). Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this this it will helps you to add your lightning application on salesforce1 tabs  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm&type=0&language=en_US